# Why is internal memory not overwritten?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, select-by-attribute, in-memory, code-review

I have the following code in Python for ArcMap to first select a property polygon and then with this selection to intersect the layer which contains lines (sewers) (which pass through or are within this polygon). In the Attribute table of the sections is a column (called "BG_HAusPfad") with the file path to its corresponding PDF.

The code then takes this file path and appends the PDF somewhere else. 
(Because we have all PDFs in one folder but need to do a folder per property with the PDFs of the sections of that polygon).

The code works for one polygon. The issue is that with the second property polygon the internal memory is still the same from before and appends the PDFs from the first property.

How can I overwrite this internal memory?

Here's the Code: (`R1_Nummer` is the number of the property polygon, aka its name. The folders of the properties are called this way)

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
R1 = r"R1_NUMMER"
field = r"BG_HAusPfad"
# that's the PDF name
PathPDF = r"I:\…\All-Separate-PDFs"
MainFolder = r"I:\…\All-Properties"

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
    pageName = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.getValue("R1_NUMMER")
    Subfolder = os.path.join(MainFolder, str(pageName))
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(r"Property-polygons", "NEW_SELECTION", "{} = '{}'".format(R1, str(pageName)))
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(selection, "in_memory\PropertySelected_lyr")
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis([r"Sewer-lines", "in_memory\PropertySelected_lyr"], "in_memory\Sewer_lyr", "ALL", "", "LINE")
    Cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(r"in_memory\Sewer_lyr")
    for row in cursor:
            Protokolname = row.getValue(field)
            ProtipdfPfad = os.path.join(PathPDF, str(Protokolname) + ".pdf")
            try:
                HprotipdfName = os.path.join(str(Subfolder), str(Protokolname) + ".pdf")
                HprotipdfDoc = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(str(HprotipdfName))
                HprotipdfDoc.appendPages(str(ProtipdfPfad))
                HprotipdfDoc.saveAndClose()
                del HprotipdfDoc
            except:
                continue
```

[image: overview of property Polygons and sewers and sewers' Attribute table]

So in the picture you see the attribute table of the sewers (the layer is actually called "A1 aufgenommen" (since it's german and very specific i just changed it in the Code to sewers for you)

Comment: Can you please format your question, parsing the code

Comment: You've deliberately obscured your question by hiding the source of the datasets, not very helpfully really if you want help? So I can only guess.If your data is in shapefile format have you added a spatial index?

Comment: You state that you *think* the issues is with SelectByLocation. Have you tried adding timing code, so that you can *know*? Please remove the interactive continuation formatting (...) so the code is more legible.

Comment: thanks for ur replies so far! 
so yes, the polygons of the properties and the lines of the sewers are in shapefiles. I have never before heard of spatial indexes, so looking that up right now and giving it a shot. I have not tried adding Timing Code, since i dont know how…? but i need to change my statement: selecting by attribute is fast and select by location works as well (a little less) fast. but apparently what is time consuming is everything afterwards, so:  the searchCursor and appending the PDFs and so on.

Comment: Your title is "Speeding up SelectbyLocation?" but the comment above suggests the slowness is to do with the PDF document creation so nothing to do with the SelectByLocation tool? Suggest you amend the title to focus peoples attention.

Comment: Are you trying to do one PDF per row in the cursor after selection, or one PDF with all of the related pages from each selection?

Comment: the spatial indexing somehow didnt wortk, my Computer just got stuck...

Comment: Yes one can only edit a comment for a few minutes and once that has expired you can only delete it. So it's definitely the select by location that is slow and you have had a problem with building spatial index. If you move your data into a file geodatabase a spatial index is automatically maintained. But I think you need to edit your question and supply details of your data, for example how many features are there in your sewer system and property layers. Spatial selections should be fast so I feel you are not telling the full story and the devil is in the detail!

Comment: Some screens are always helpful.

Comment: so i adapted the Code and it's already waaay faster than with select by Location. 

any conceptual advices on how to change the in_memory layers???

Comment: @smiller one PDF per row. We want to Keep the PDFs apart.

Comment: @Hornbydd here's a Picture for the overview… :-)

Comment: @Hornbydd and we have 214 property Polygons and 506 sewer lines. But this is only for that Region. In arcmap we have manymany more properties (5010) and more sewers (14602). So to work with the sewers and properties of interest, I did a Preselection. But Maybe this is why select by Location takes so long?